# BottomNavigationBarItem padding for page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to BottomNavigationBarItem on top of Camera widget if camera more then height screen and bottom naviagtion But i have elemets in bottom in camera widget and it is problem.
If i do this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(

          child: CameraScreen(),

        ),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context)
                    .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
                child: BottomNavigationBar(
                  currentIndex: 0,
                  items: [
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home')
                  ],
                ))),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

elements in Camera widget dont display right:

[image]

I want the camera to be full screen and be visible behind the buttom navigation menu and the camera elements to be at the top of the  buttom navigation menu

any idea?

Maybe i need to get height from buttom navigator and add this height to padding elements in camera widget?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 Scaffold(
    extendBody: true,
    body: bodyWidgetTree(),
    bottomNavigationBar: yourBottomNavBar(),
)
```